# Hue: Search for all tables containing a certain field

Tags: hive, hue

I am trying to identify all the tables that contain a certain column (for example, “thenameoffield”) using Hue

In the Hue User Guide under Data Catalogs, it suggests entering type:field name in the search bar, but when I do this there are no results found.  There are no clear examples in the documentation, but I assume "name" is the name of the field I want to search for.  The documentation does not state if wildcard can be used, such as "*name*".  I did try this but no results were produced.

I also tried running SQL queries, but based on the error messages, Hue does not accept the syntax (assuming it's correct to start with):
I. Entering the syntax above into the Hue query area:
type:field(column): ‘thenameoffield’ AND
type:field 'thenameoffield'
with and without quotes, but it doesn’t work. *“AnalysisException: Syntax error in line2:undefined: type:field(column): /thenameoffield’”*
II. I also tried:
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
but not working either- “AnalysisException: Syntax error in line2:undefined: EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM,…Exception: Syntax error”
III.  I also attempted to use:
SELECT
sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
tables.name AS TableName
FROM
sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE
sys.columns.name LIKE ‘%thenameoffield%’

but received the error message: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1: undefined: SELECT sys.columns.name as ColumnName,…

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Catalog search](https://docs.gethue.com/user/browsing/#data-catalogs) is currently powered by either Apache Atlas or Cloudera Navigator so you would need to point Hue to those to make it work.

About the DB metadata querying, you might have more chance by tagging the question with Apache Hive instead of Hue (as Hue just sends the query to Hive). Would also help to have the Hive verion.

Comment: Thank you.  Instructions on how to point to Apache Atlas would be helpful.  I changed the editor to Hive and tried querying, but same error messages.  Why does Hive not accept the use of SQL code using Information_Schema?